# Connecting constraint removes margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

When I'm programmatically setting a constraint, the side wherein I'll connect the view to another view seems to be losing the margin (I already have a margin set for the view):

```
bottomLineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ConstraintSet mainConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
mainConstraintSet.clone(mainConstraintLayout);
mainConstraintSet.connect(bottomLineView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, connectingViewId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
mainConstraintSet.applyTo(mainConstraintLayout);
termsAndConditionsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I'm aware that I can get the margin then apply it

```
mainConstraintSet.connect(bottomLineView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, bottomViewId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_huge));
```

But is there anyway to leave the margin be?

Comment: Is this issue still no solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no solution. This feature may be added in a future release.